# Best practice on where to store my.cnf configuration with MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

After a small update ran by an Ansible playbook from `MariaDB 10.5.4` to `MariaDB 10.5.5`, the custom configuration file got *silently* overriden by the default configuration causing the server to refuse connection because the valid custom configuration was no longer present.

Our custom configuration file was stored under `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

My question is: What is the **best practice** to store the custom configuration so it **never again gets replaced by the default one when an update comes out**

Is it `/etc/mysql/conf.d/` ?

Distribution: Debian 10 installed with the official repository: `https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.5/repo/debian`

Comment: I'd say that depends on the distribution and how MariaDB was installed (system, third party repo, from source etc.)

Comment: It's a Debian 10 :)

Comment: It was installed with the official repository: https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.5/repo/debian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're meant to leave the default configuration alone and place your configuration snippets in files in `/etc/my.cnf.d/` (the location used by MariaDB upstream) or Debian's nonstandard location `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/` or wherever your particular MariaDB packages locate this directory.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating an ansible patches role that will store you customized my.cnf file and in case it does not match content will be updated.

Our best practice we do is to run a patch role after every update is done to ensure all customizations will be in place. It saved us a lot of time with this practice.